# Can I change the play icon of embedded youtube videos?

Tags: css, youtube

Am I allowed to replace the original youtube play icon on embedded youtube videos? I would place my own icon above the youtube iframe to achieve that. I know that facebook does not allow to style the like button, so that's why I am asking about youtube player customization.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure you can customise a YouTube embedded without using the YouTube JavaScript api.

Heres how to do it with the api:

**Javascript**

```
//youtube script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '244',
        width: '434',
        videoId: 'AkyQgpqRyBY',  // youtube video id
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 0,
            'rel': 0,
            'showinfo': 0
        },
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

onPlayerStateChange = function (event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        $('.start-video').fadeIn('normal');
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.start-video', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('normal');
    player.playVideo();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="player"></div>
<button class="start-video">Start Video</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 106px;
    padding: 12px;
    left: 174px;
}
```

I've created a **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeUFb/)** with a working example.

Comment: This is not working, you can see the youtube button underneath your custom button in the fiddle.

Comment: Not for me @roNn23, in Chrome the linked fiddle from AfromanJ looks good and ist customizable.