# How can I change my iframe video background image?

Tags: html, css

I am using iframe to show a video on my site and want to change the styling of the play button.

Here my code:

```css
.ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image {
 background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
}

button.ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

```html
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
```

How can I put my background-image and change the button styling?

Comment: Try this thread.., [Custom play button youtube video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627887/youtube-custom-play-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code with javascript.

```css
#background-video {
        background-image: url('http://placehold.it/580x460');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding: 50px;
}

#vidwrap {
        background: url('http://www.edu.uwo.ca/img/click_to_play.png') no-repeat center;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:480px;
        height:360px;
        cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div id="background-video">
        <div onclick="play();" id="vidwrap"></div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">function play(){document.getElementById('vidwrap').innerHTML = '<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/7-7knsP2n5w?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';}</script>
```

Comment: Thank it works. I still wanted to be able to style the button, but your code works and I vote for it]